# C# get texts in all html nodes and replace them with translateds

Tags: c#, html, parsing, translate, yandex

I am writing a tool too translate html file content in c#.

I am using `HtmlAgilityPack` to work with html nodes and `YandexTranslateCSharpSdk` for translating text's.(i met with both newly)

My algorithm is getting texts in any html node and replace it with translated.

one problem is that `HtmlAgilityPack`returns all conent in html tag when i using `node.innerText` and other is that i have no idea to speedup translating process, when i get a text from node and translate it with online tool surely takes many time.
The code Looks like this:

```
foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            //i++;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.InnerText) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText))
                continue;
            var trans = await wrapper.TranslateText(node.InnerText.Replace("\n", "").Trim(), "en-fr");
            if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {

                node.ReplaceChild(doc.CreateTextNode(trans), node.ChildNodes.First());
            }
            else
            {
                node.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(trans));
            }

        }
```

In HtmlAgilityPack the `node.innerText` is read only and can not use `node.innerText="some text"` for solving it i used this code:

```
if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                {

                    node.ReplaceChild(doc.CreateTextNode(trans), node.ChildNodes.First());
                }
                else
                {
                    node.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(trans));
                }
```

But is not works.